# Do Heaven or Hell have Technologies​ like we have on Earth?

Tags: gods

In our stories too, we see Rishis and Gods travelling miles and miles on Foot.

There were Vimanas but not everyone had them.

Letters were posted via messengers.

But now, on Earth, we have excellent Technologies​.

**Do the Heavens and Hells, and the higher realms use technologies​?**

**Do Indra, Chandra, Surya, and other use technologies like we do?**

Comment: What do you mean by technologies here? Which type of technologies are you looking for?

Comment: Don't worry dude, they have more technologies (Even IT -  computers), like Vimanas, time traveler, Kamadhenu etc.  The (Moon's) Chandra powerful pull influences on every living thing on our planet. Surya (sun) has powerful  hydrogen and helium nuclei energy (More than Nuclear energy). if Indra, Chandra, Surya use their technology we can't see next day. So what type of technologies you are taking about here?

Comment: Human body is macrocosm. Devas are spiritually evolved beings than us.  They even break laws of physics with their Sukshma sareeras. But all technology of human is for Stula World or Physical world. Humans are not unleashing their hidden powers or not knowing their self and trying to find happiness or comforts through Physical things or through their Sthula Sareera. Why do they need our technology, when they are more evolved than us?